# Is there any way to remove wiggle in these UVs?

Tags: mesh, uv, distort

so I got this piece of mesh:

[image: image description here]

I'd like texture to follow curvature of the mesh, but it gives that wiggly UV distortion:

[image]

I know that it might not be that noticeable but this part will be viewed from up close so I need to get rid of it.

Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: When you unwrap a UV (Keyboard U) you will see a small menu on the left bottom corner, there you could select the option "Use Subdivision Surface", try that.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly solution, but some info ...

**Cube** (8 vertices)
[image]

It looks like blender triangulates faces (they are triangulated for render anyway) and just shears the texture.

**Cube** with *Subdivision* modifier
[image]

Looks straight at Level 3. At Level 4 (1088 vertices) not noticeable a movement at all in the texture.

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing the triangulation of the mesh, because of UV distortion:

[image]

The problem is that we have long skinny trapezoids, which get triangulated into unevenly sized triangles, and we're mapping them to UV rectangles.  The center of the UV gets mapped to the center of the diagonal, but for the mesh, the center of the diagonal is not in the center of the face, but off to one side, and the line that runs straight through the UV actually runs in two angled segments along the mesh, creating a wiggle.

There are two things we can do to fix this.  Neither on its own is a good solution, but we can adapt them together into a good solution.  First, we can cut some loops here, to make those trapezoids less long and skinny:

[image]

As we add loops, the trapezoids approach squares, reducing UV distortion and reducing the impact of triangulation.  We will never completely get rid of the wiggle, but we can get rid of it to any arbitrary level of precision, just by using more vertices.  The reason this is not a good solution is because we are adding to the vertex count of the mesh.

The other thing we can do is eliminate UV distortion:

[image]

If we map those positional trapezoids to UV trapezoids, we can no longer see the triangulation.  The reason this is not a good solution is because we're not mapping the texture in the same way.

But if we make a copy of this mesh with loop cuts, and a copy of this mesh without UV distortion, we can bake the texture from one to the other:

[image]

We could bake the loop cut version to our original UV instead if we wanted, but if we're going to bake, we can afford undistorted UV.  After all, we may be deforming this shape later, making our triangulation apparent once again.  The less that the base UV is distorted, the less distorted it will be under unpredictable deformation.  Even if it won't be deformed, the less distorted UV will give us more even texel density which is generally preferable.